# use browser session to prevent user to submit the form more than 1 time

Tags: php, session, post, session-cookies

I have a details page which url look like this

```
https://example.com/details.php?id=20123
```

The page content changes based on ?id= at the end.

I have a form on this page.. and what I'm trying to achieve is to prevent user to submit the form more than once for that id

By "that id" I mean... if page is id=20 - not more than once for id 20
if page is id: 21 - alow once but not more than 1 time
etc..

I can't figure out how can I check the page url id + check the user..

I'm getting the id part from url with `$url = $_GET['id'];`

Then checking user:

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
if(isset($_SESSION['form_submitted']))
  {
    die('You have already submitted the form.');
  }
else
  {
    #submitted form code here
    $_SESSION['form_submitted'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

Can someone help me please to combine these and check the page id + the user too.. in order to not allow the same user to submit the form more than once for the same post id

Comment: Where is the user information stored? You mention it but I don't see any reference to user information in what you posted.

Comment: You need to pass the id field up with your form submission. This can be done in a few ways, Either a hidden field in your form or adding it in with javascript before making the ajax call to submit your form. Then you can access the id with $_POST[“id”]. You might want to store a list of the ids in a $_SESSION variable so you can check against them in your if-else statements. If you want to persist this behaviour across sessions, then you need to store the id and userId as a pair in a database and query

Comment: Why is there the `regex` tag?